# Oracle query for finding the records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I am not getting any result from the below 2 queries. Please let me know if anything is wrong in this queries.

1. Display all records where the gender is female and salary is greater than 5000.50 and birth_date is between the Unix Timestamp values of '946684800' and '1609372800'

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSON 
where gender = 'female' and salary  > '5000.50'  and birth_date BETWEEN to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 946684800/24/60/60/1000  and to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1609372800/24/60/60/1000;
```

2. Display the number of records grouped by gender and salary (where salary is rounded up to the nearest thousandth)

SELECT count(*), gender FROM PERSON  where ceiling(salary/1000.0)*1000 group by gender;

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the problem is the fiter on the dates. You seem to assume that `946684800` is a unix epoch *in milliseconds*, while it looks like it is expressed in seconds.

Consider:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

-- your expression
select to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 946684800/24/60/60/1000 dt from dual

| DT                  |
| :------------------ |
| 1970-01-11 22:58:05 |

-- isn't this better?
select to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 946684800/24/60/60 dt from dual

| DT                  |
| :------------------ |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
```

I would also recommend giving a literal number to the filer on salary rather than a string (unexpected things happen when you compare values of different datatypes). Finally, date literals should be preferred to `to_date()` whenever possible.

You could phrase the query as:

```
select * 
from person 
where 
    gender = 'female' 
    and salary > 5000.50 
    and birth_date between date '1970-01-01' +  946684800/24/60/60 
                       and date '1970-01-01' + 1609372800/24/60/60;
```

Comment: Display the number of records grouped by gender and salary (where salary is rounded up to the nearest thousandth)

SELECT count(*), gender FROM PERSON where ceiling(salary/1000.0)*1000 group by gender;

Comment: @user2547994: asking multiple questions in a single question is bad practice in Stack Overflow. I would recommend [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this.